# Boto3 EC2 CreateSnapshots Validation Error with ExcludeDataVolumeIds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to create snapshots with Boto3.

```
snapshot_response = client.create_snapshots(
    Description='super important backup',
    InstanceSpecification={
        'InstanceId': 'i-something',
        'ExcludeBootVolume': True,
        'ExcludeDataVolumeIds': ['vol-something1','vol-something2'],
    },
    CopyTagsFromSource='volume'
)
```

But if fails with this error.

```
[ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in InstanceSpecification: \"ExcludeDataVolumeIds\", must be one of: InstanceId, ExcludeBootVolume
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/something/some_dir/some_script.py\", line 50, in some_function
    snapshot_response = client.create_snapshots(
  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 691, in _make_api_call
    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(
  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 739, in _convert_to_request_dict
    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(
  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py\", line 360, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())END
```

Has anyone got this sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not try with boto3, but with CLI I was facing the same error. I resolved it by upgrading the CLI version to v2.11 (the latest).
In your case, maybe upgrading the boto3 and botocore modules might solve it.

```
pip install botocore --upgrade
pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

Comment: yes, I had this issue with a lambda function. It was fixed when they upgraded the boto3 version. Thanks for the answer!